# Snowflake copy command failing in validation mode

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using python script to load the data from S3 bucket to Snowflake stage table. It was working fine but all of a sudden facing issue with copy command in validation mode. Not sure what caused the issue can anyone help me to debug the issue please.

Below is the error which I'm getting when copy command is executed in validation mode. However without validation mode I can load the data into prestage table. I gone through snowflake doc that Validation mode doesn't support COPY statements that transform data during a load. But not sure how it has ran fine without any issue all these years and all of a sudden getting error. There was no change happened to script.

```
 002352 (0A000): SQL compilation error:
 VALIDATION_MODE does not support COPY with transform.
```

Note: The source file is delimited with pipe and using customized csv file format to load the data into prestage table. Please find below the copy command which is used in validation mode. Any help to debug the issue with validation mode copy command is much appreciated.

```
copy into PRESTG_TABLE from ( select F.$1, F.$2, F.$3, F.$4, F.$5, F.$6, F.$7, 
F.$8, F.$9, F.$10, F.$11, F.$12, F.$13, F.$14, F.$15, F.$16, F.$17, F.$18, F.$19, F.$20, F.$21, 
F.$22, F.$23, F.$24, F.$25, F.$26, F.$27, F.$28, F.$29, F.$30, F.$31, F.$32, F.$33, F.$34, F.$35, 
F.$36, F.$37, F.$38, F.$39, F.$40, F.$41, F.$42, F.$43, F.$44, F.$45, F.$46, F.$47, F.$48, F.$49, 
F.$50, F.$51, F.$52, F.$53, F.$54, F.$55, F.$56, F.$57, F.$58, F.$59, F.$60, F.$61, F.$62, F.$63, 
F.$64, F.$65, F.$66, F.$67, F.$68, F.$69, F.$70, F.$71, F.$72, F.$73, F.$74, F.$75, F.$76, F.$77, 
F.$78, F.$79, F.$80, F.$81, F.$82, F.$83, F.$84, F.$85, F.$86, F.$87, F.$88, F.$89, F.$90, F.$91, 
F.$92, F.$93, F.$94, F.$95, F.$96, F.$97, F.$98, F.$99, F.$100, F.$101, F.$102, F.$103, F.$104, 
F.$105, F.$106, F.$107, F.$108, F.$109, F.$110, F.$111, F.$112, F.$113, F.$114, F.$115, F.$116, 
F.$117, F.$118, F.$119, F.$120, F.$121, F.$122, F.$123, F.$124, F.$125, F.$126, F.$127, F.$128, 
F.$129, F.$130, F.$131, F.$132, F.$133, F.$134, F.$135, F.$136, F.$137, F.$138, F.$139, F.$140, 
F.$141, F.$142, F.$143, F.$144, F.$145, F.$146, F.$147, F.$148, F.$149, F.$150, F.$151, F.$152, 
F.$153, F.$154, F.$155, F.$156, F.$157, F.$158, F.$159, F.$160, F.$161, F.$162, F.$163, F.$164, 
F.$165, F.$166, F.$167, F.$168, F.$169, F.$170, F.$171, F.$172, F.$173, F.$174, F.$175, F.$176, 
F.$177, F.$178, F.$179, F.$180, F.$181, F.$182, F.$183, F.$184, F.$185, F.$186, F.$187, F.$188, 
F.$189, F.$190, F.$191, F.$192, F.$193, F.$194, F.$195, F.$196, F.$197, F.$198, F.$199, F.$200, 
F.$201, F.$202, F.$203, F.$204, F.$205, F.$206, F.$207, F.$208, F.$209, F.$210, F.$211, F.$212, 
F.$213, F.$214, F.$215, F.$216, F.$217, F.$218, F.$219, F.$220, F.$221, F.$222, F.$223, F.$224, 
F.$225, F.$226, F.$227, F.$228, F.$229, F.$230, F.$231, F.$232, F.$233, F.$234, F.$235, F.$236, 
SCHEMA.RECORD_SEQUENCE.nextval, F.$238, F.$239, metadata$filename from 
@PATH/TO/FILE F )
FORCE = False FILE_FORMAT =  (FORMAT_NAME = 'LANDING_CSV') pattern = '.*.*' on_error = 'continue' VALIDATION_MODE='RETURN_ALL_ERRORS'
```

Please find below the sample source file record

```
PJT_DETAILS|PJT-47213|AGILE|AGILE_PJT_DETAILS|21352180PJT-47213|2019-08-20 07:10:59|21352180|PJT-47213|82398|Implemented|6141|PJT|235815|NR = Not Required|Prod: description|200452|Release|Production Release Package. Distribution - General.|82379|Release Workflow|1201283386|FNAME LNAME|29380|FNAME LNAME|2019-08-06 19:39:04|2019-08-20 03:47:01|2019-08-20 03:47:05|,3399696,|EX|||| No AVL||||||||||||2019-08-13 03:05:21||244733|N/A||Success|||236080|N/A|||||,3394985,|Software|Helpful Hints.|Any post-production PJT change |2460788|No|WEB RELEASE.||Use the following guidelines |3378007|No|WEB RELEASE.||Indicate Yes or No ||||||3380751|Manual|3380749|N/A|3406070|Yes|||219355|Not Defined||241694|N/A|219362|Not Defined||1377263|N/A|2460244|Not Defined||2462619|Not Defined||2460267|Not Defined||2460254|Not Defined||Not Defined||3760463|Not Defined|||||Not Defined||Not Defined||750.000000||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||0|0||0||||0||||Not Defined||||Not Defined|2019-08-06 19:39:04|2019-08-20 07:10:59|0||UnProcessed||
```

Comment: So it ran all the time both in VALIDATION_MODE and had transformations inside?

Comment: Yes @Marcel... The copy statement which I shared is the same which worked fine but now failing not sure what has caused the issue. The source file will have NULL values in the place of #237 and #240 columns which is delimited by "|" were it has been populated by Sequence Id and Filename respectively in the copy command for each record. This was working fine since 2018 and now its getting failed stating transformation not allowed during copy.

Comment: VALIDATION_MODE does not support COPY statements that transform data during a load. If the parameter is specified, the COPY statement returns an error. See [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#optional-parameters)

Comment: @Sergiu.. The script have ran fine by specifying the validation_mode parameter in the copy command earlier but now the same is getting failed not sure if there was any update happened to SNOWFLAKE or something I'm missing. Don't have idea on debugging further...

Comment: To help debug it, I would start by replacing columns with NULL (or any value that the column will accept) to try and isolate where the problem is. The obvious place to start is with the SCHEMA.RECORD_SEQUENCE.nextval and metadata$filename columns: my guess would be that SCHEMA.RECORD_SEQUENCE.nextval is being treated as a transformation